# Having a custom repository not associated to an entity in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `DefaultRepository` file to place all the general queries there.

Would be possible to have a custom repository not associated with an entity in Symfony? I would like to put in it some native SQL that doesn't fit well in other repositories (it may refer to abstract or entity hierarchy).

How controller code:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepositoty(/* ??? */) should be replaced?
```

Comment: Inject the repository.  You should not be using the getRepo for anything that is reasonably up to date.

Comment: What do you mean by "some native SQL" ? Please be more specific to describe what you want to do. You could add some sugar with `QueryBuilder` creation and manipulation for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not a repository. A repository is linked to an Entity in Doctrine and provide functions like "findOneBy", etc...
Out of the context of an entity, it doesn't make sense. 
If you need to store custom queries, you can still add a service and inject in it the Doctrine Manager (or only the entity repositories you need). 
Then, you can use your service easily in controller.

In your services.yaml file, you would have something like this :

```
services:
    App\Services\QueriesManager:
        autowire: true
```

Your service would look like (App\Services\QueriesManager)

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class QueriesManager {
    protected $entityManager;

    __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getSpecialQueryResult() {
        $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select(...)
           ->where(...)
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

And in your controller, you can just type-hint it on the method you want to use it, like:

```
class MyController {
    public function indexAction($param1, \App\Services\QueriesManager $queriesManager) {
        return $queriesManager->getSpecialQueryResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the error: "Notice: Undefined variable: queriesManager" What is the problem?

Comment: You probably have a typo somewhere... Missing '$' or something.

Comment: It does not work the way you indicate to call from the controller, at the moment I have it like this: $query = $em->getRepository('BackendBundle:Users')->searchAdvance($var,$var1,$var2,$var3);
But using your solution as it would be?

Comment: My solution relies on autowiring to inject the service. The service is not a repository, so you can't call it from the $em->getRepository method.

Comment: Ok. Now I use the service in controller: $query=$this->get('app.queriesmanager')->searchAdvance($var,$var1,$var2,$var3); but show this error: "Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Services\QueriesManager::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session given, called in /var/www/html/amalia/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 532" The line is this: public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) { //File QueriesManager.php

Answer (score 1):

You can have a custom, generic "repository", but you would not retrieve it via the Doctrine EntityManager. Instead you inject it directly to the Controller.

Your repository could look something like this:

```
class MyRepository implements RepositoryInterface
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function findFoo()
    {
        $builder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

        $query = $builder->... // build query

        return $query->getResult();
    }

    // Implement the generic find-methods defined by the interface
}
```

Implementing the interface is not mandatory, when you use the repository directly, but will make it feel more familiar. By injecting the entityManager you can just call other repositories to fetch data or create a query builder for writing your own queries.

In your controller you would then inject the repository or get it from the container, e.g. like this:

```
class FooController extends Controller
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(MyRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $foo = $this->repository->findFoo();
    }
}
```

You can also define your repository as service:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.my_repository:
        class: App\Repository\MyRepository
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
```

and then retrieve your repository in controllers with the helper method, instead of injecting it:

```
$this->get('app.my_repository');
```

Please note, that:

- Since you can not really use the methods defined by the RepositoryInterface, as you do not want to work with a single entity, where e.g. `findOneBy` would make sense, it might make sense not to implement the interface.
- You could also give these classes a different name. For instance you could put each query into their own class and have a `FindFooQuery` class that you inject as service into your controller. That way it is more clear, that this is in fact not tied to an entity, but it's own kind of thing. This might make this approach more manageable when you have many queries.

Comment: I use this line in controller: $query=$this->get('app.my_repository')->searchAdvance($var,$var1,$var2,$var3); But this is the error: "Type error: Too few arguments to function Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct(), 1 passed in /var/www/html/amalia/var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 431 and exactly 2 expected" What is the error?

Comment: You have to configure the repository in your `services.yml`. It seems you have 2 arguments, instead of 1 in my example. If you have a newer Symfony version (3.4 or 4.0 upwards) you can use autowiring for this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html
Otherwise you have to adjust the config I have added above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

This is the solution for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53098008/2400373

Use symfony 3.3.x Here I make a summary of how to solve my problem

File service.yml:

```
//service.yml
services:
     app.queriesmanager:
          class: AppBundle\Services\QueriesManager
          autowire: true
```

File AppBundle\Services\QueriesManager.php

```
//AppBundle\Services\QueriesManager.php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class QueriesManager  {
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function searchAdvance($var,$var1,$var2,$var3)
    {
        $dql1 = "";
        $dql2 = "";
        $dql = "SELECT pl
                      FROM BackendBundle:Products p
                      JOIN BackendBundle:Pricelist pl
                      WITH p.peachitemid =  pl.peachitemid
                      WHERE p.hasimages =  1
                      AND p.active = 'FALSE'
                      AND p.imagesamazon1 = 1
                      AND p.imagesamazon2 = 1
                      AND (p.descriptionforsales like '%$var%' OR p.itemid like '%$var%')";

        if ($var1 != "select") {
            $dql1 = " AND p.newcategory='$var1' AND p.newsubcategory='$var2' ";
        }
        if ($var3 == "150") {
            $dql2 = " AND pl.retail < 150";
        }
        if ($var3 == "200") {
            $dql2 = " AND pl.retail > 150 AND pl.retail < 250 ";
        }
        if ($var3 == "250") {
            $dql2 = " AND pl.retail > 250 ";
        }

        $dql1 .= $dql2;
        $dql .= $dql1;
        $query=$this->entityManager->createQuery($dql);
        $query = $query->getResult();
        return $query;

    }
}
```

File DefaultController.php

```
//Use the service in controller
$query=$this->get('app.queriesmanager')->searchAdvance($var,$var1,$var2,$var3);
```

**Update**

For symfony 4.x you need to change the lines in the service

```
app.queriesmanager:
        class: App\Services\QueriesManager
        public: true
```

Thanks you and I hope you can help.